# Prove $\int_1^{\infty}\psi(x)(x^\frac{s}{2}+ x^\frac{1-s}{2})\frac{dx}{x} $ is Entire

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-functions, riemann-hypothesis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Define $$f(s)= \int_1^{\infty}\psi(x)(x^\frac{s}{2}+  x^\frac{1-s}{2})\frac{dx}{x} $$ where $ \psi(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n^2\pi x}$ is the Jacobi Theta function.

Claim- $f(s)$ is Entire

My Try :-
$s=a+ib$ then $f(a+ib)=u(a,b)+iv(a,b)$ satisfy Cauchy Riemann Equations. How to proceed?

Comment: @Luna 145 Any clue for the question?

Comment: This is not my background. I simply was fixing your LaTeX. Apologies.

Comment: @Luna 145 Ok thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: $f$ converges for all $s$ and it is a bit obvious that $f'= ...\ $ (so that $f$ is holomorphic)

Comment: @reuns How it is obvious?? Differentiation under the integral sign for improper integrals is valid?

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your quick reply sir.

Comment: Where do you see an improper integral ? Here it is of course valid, for example because $x^{s/2} = x^{s_0}(1+\log(x) (s-s_0)/2+O( \min 1, (s-s_0)^2 \log^2 x))$

Comment: @reuns we have an improper integral from 1 to $\infty$. What you just wrote for $x^{s/2} $ i did not understand why it is relevant sir.

Comment: @reuns s is a complex number.

Comment: @reuns Please reply sir

Answer (score 1):

$$g(s)=\int_1^\infty \psi(x) x^s dx$$ converges for all $s$.
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(s+h)-g(s)}{h}- \int_1^\infty \psi(x) \log(x)x^s dx $$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}  \int_1^\infty \psi(x) \int_s^{s+h}\log(x) \frac{x^z-x^s}{h} dz dx$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}  \int_1^\infty \psi(x) \int_s^{s+h}\log(x)\frac1{h} \int_s^z \log(x) x^u dudz dx$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}  \int_1^\infty \psi(x) O(h \log^2(x) x^{1+s}) dx=0$$
Thus $$g'(s)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(s+h)-g(s)}{h}=\int_1^\infty \psi(x) \log(x)x^s dx $$ and $g$ is complex differentiable, for all $s$, it is holomorphic on the whole complex plane, by the Cauchy integral formula it is entire (analytic everywhere) and everywhere equal to its Taylor series at $s_0$.

Comment: You are awesome sir. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: How do you get the big O term??

Comment: $\int_s^{s+h}\int_s^z x^u dudz = O(h^2 x^s)$ because we are integrating something $O(x^s)$ on segments of length $\le h$

Comment: Any other simpler proof?

Comment: What don't you like in thisone ? saying $O(h^2 x^{1+s})$ is probably more correct. There are a lot of theorems about holomorphicity but in the theory of $\zeta(s)$ you have to be confortable with the raw calculation

Comment: Last question. Is this improper integral bounded???

Comment: @ShekharSuman $\psi(x)$ is $\mathcal O(e^{-cx^2}$ for some constant $c>0$, so it is evident that this integral converges for all $s\in\mathbb C$